# How to determine $\lim _{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I want to find $\lim _{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$.

How can I get rid of the indeterminate form $\infty * 0$ ?

I now it is supposed to be $1$ , but I really don't see how can I start, I am only at my first year so I only know the most basic things for limits.

Comment: $$\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\int_1^{1+1/n}\frac{dx}x\implies\frac1n\cdot\frac1{1+1/n}\leqslant\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\leqslant\frac1n\cdot1\implies n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\to1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1** (Derivatives)

For $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, $f^\prime(0) = 1$. Now, $$f^\prime(0) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-0}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}.$$

**Method #2** (Taylor expansions) *[a bit less elementary, but damn useful method]*

**Hint:** when $u\to0$, you have $\ln(1+u) = u + o(u)$.

**Detailed:** Then,

> $$n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = n\left(\frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = 1 + o(1) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$$

Comment: To show the contents of the grayed box, place your mouse over it.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that by the continuity of $\ln$ you have
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)
= \ln\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)
= \ln(e)
= 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+{1\over n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \ln\big(\big(1+{1\over n}\big)^n\big)  = \ln(e) = 1$$

Comment: and you can bring the limit inside the $\ln$ because it's a continuos function. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Set $1/n=h$ to get

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$$

OR set $\ln(1+u)=x\implies u=e^x-1$  to find  $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=?$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** One has: $$\ln(1+x)\underset{x\to 0}{=}x+o(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard tricks for $0 \cdot \infty$ is to turn it into $\infty / \infty$ or $0/0$.

In particular, a *standard* trick here is

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = 
\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{1/n}$$

to turn it into a new limit problem... one for which there is a standard trick for dealing with.