# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\cdot \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ without l'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

This seems relatively easy to do with l'Hôpital, once you establish the following equality:

$x\cdot \ln(1+\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\ln(1+\frac1x) }{\frac{1}{x}}$

Take the derivatives and the answer is 1.

What I'm trying to do is to solve it without using l'Hôpital, but I'm quite stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1598396/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could  use $$y-\frac12y^2\le \ln(1+y)<y$$ for $y>0$. This is from using the Taylor series as an  alternating series.

Or use the mean value theorem for the fraction:
$$
\frac{\ln(1+y)-\ln(1)}{(1+y)-1}
$$

---

Depending on if that was your definition of the logarithm, you could also use
$$
x\ln(1+\frac1x)=x(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x))=x\int_x^{x+1}\frac{dt}t=\int_0^1\frac{x\,ds}{x+s}=\int_0^1\frac{ds}{1+\frac{s}x}
$$
and as the integrand is bounded and continuous and the integration interval compact, you can switch limit and integral to get $\int_0^1ds=1$ as result.

Comment: What would the $lim_{y\rightarrow 0}$ of the last fraction be equal to?

Comment: The derivative of $f(y)=\ln(1+y)$ at $y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(u)=\ln(1+u)$.

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(u+1)-\ln(1)}{u-0}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{g(u)-g(0)}{u-0}=g'(0)=1.$$

Comment: Why don't we multiply $g'(0)$ with the derivative of $u$ in the penultimate step of the equation? Isn't that what chain rule requires? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Aaand the answer happens to be no, the limit is equivalent to $g'(0)$ and not $[g(0)]'$. Please correct me if I'm still wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Glycerius: By definition $f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

Comment: I consider this to be the One True Answer, by the way, though the other answers are correct. Identifying a derivative is a lovely way to solve limits.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this novel one page proof: 
http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf
which explains without l'Hôpital's rule that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$$
Now your question just involves taking the natural logarithm of both sides from above.  So your answer follows from this quite easily, and is given by $$\ln e=1.$$