# Solving $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ and indeterminate form

Tags: limits

How can I solve $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ ?
I end up getting an indeterminated form...

Comment: let $x = \frac{1}{t}$ and then use     LH rule

Comment: See the [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20x%5Cln%20(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D)%24&p=1) search results.

Comment: Have you learned about L'Hopital rule? If yes, then the answer below is helpful. Can you tell us what have you learned about calculating the limit?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng No I don't know about L'Hopital's. I thought about using $x\ln(x)$ when x goes to $0$...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\cdot \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ without l'Hôpital's Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020304/evaluate-lim-x-rightarrow-inftyx-cdot-ln1-frac1x-without-lh%c3%b4pital)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \log (1+1/x)=$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \log (1+1/x)^x=$

$\log (\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1+1/x)^x)=$

$\log e=1.$

Used:

$\log$ is continuos, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+1/x)^x=e.$

Comment: how do you go from $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \log (1+1/x)^x$ to $e$ ?

Comment: nginx101. Last line in the answer. This is one of the well known representations of e. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Answer (score 3):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln{(1+\frac{1}{x})}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}\cdot (-\frac{1}{x^2})}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Without using L'Hopital's:

$$ \lim _{x\to \infty }x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }x\left({\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+.....}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left({1-\frac{1}{2x}+.....}\right)=1$$

(using $\ln(1+x)$ expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and $f(t)=\ln(1+t)$, then we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)-\ln(1+0)}{t-0}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0}=f'(0)$$
$$=\frac{1}{t+1}\big|_{t=0}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$
Substitute $z=\dfrac 1x$:
$$L=\lim _{z\to 0 }\left(\dfrac {\ln(1+z)}z\right)$$
Apply L'Hôpital's rule:
$$L=\lim _{z\to 0 }\dfrac 1 {1+z}=1$$